# How can i add Hidden input field like HTML in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I want to add some hidden field in Flex and send to the server

please tell me the solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Err... Use any variable/object to store the value and send it as a part of your request object.

Answer (score 1):

use `visible` property in form item.

Answer (score 0):

What do you use to send it to server currently?
I'm using flex, to send data to server I may use 2 ways:

1. using httpservice, just call httpservice and pass the params.  See http://oodaemon.sourceforge.net/
2. Using remoteobject (I used this with java).  Mapping the java class with graniteds, then just pass the param to the remoteobject.

What issue do you have right now?